# position:absolute in dynamic sized element in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-position

I'm here with a question about CSS in IE8 and asking for possible workarounds.

I have a site with a sort-of-sticky-footer.

I have a **div** that is *100%-100%* in *size*, in a **body** element with set *min-width* and *min-height*.

Which means the **div** is stretched to the window size unless the window is too small, in that case, scrollbars appear.

Inside that **div**, I have another **div** element (a sticky footer), with *absolute position* to the *bottom* of the **div**. *The min-height* of the body is set exactly that when the footer **div** hits the page's content it stops moving up, so it doesn't overlap with the content. Now it works good in all browsers except **IE8**. There are always problems with IE8...

What it does on IE8 is, that during the page's loading the footer **div** sets itself on the bottom of the screen, **regardless of the min-height**, so on small screens it overlaps with the content **and** scrolling doesn't move it, so it just stays frozen wherever it appears on the page.

So it seems that the problem isn't in the footer, but the main **div** not resizing to *100%* of the screen...

What can I do about it?

You can check it [here](http://www.brejcha-blatna.cz/?page_id=12)
(the page's code is horrible, I just got it to fix some stuff that's not working and optimizing it for IE8 is a tough, tough job)

---

Under the line: Shouldn't there be a separate StackExchange site for webdesign? I mean, stackoverflow is for enthusiastic **programmers** and webdesign isn't really programming unless we're asking about PHP, JS etc. which isn't much about design...

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood the issue but it sounds to me like the footer isn't correctly contained within the div.
To fix this, add: `position: relative`
to the div

Comment: `position:relative` seems to be default in chrome, so when I add the rule and then disable it in the Developer Tools, it does the same thing as IE8. So I guess it's correct to use `position:relative`, as some browsers might not have this by default.
However, IE8 still stays the same way. What's good to note is, that when I scroll, the footer doesn't stick to the bottom of the screen, but stays where the bottom of the screen was when the page loaded.
(check [this](http://i.imgur.com/5FrXa3x.png) and [this](http://i.imgur.com/ePIEs3I.png)).

Comment: Although resizing does move it to the bottom of the screen (or to be more precise where the bottom is when the page is scrolled up) Give me a while and I'll add red coloring to the fullscreen div...
So it seems that IE8 is ignoring my min-height, because it always resizes to 100% of the screen's size regardless of the min-height rule.

Comment: Just fixed it. What was happening was that the **fullscreen** div was resized to 100% of the screen in IE8, whereas in Chrome and most other browsers it resized to 100% of the parent (body) that had min-height set.

So basically just setting the min-height for the **fullscreen** element as well worked.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you; i didn't get an email about this for some reason...

Comment: But glad to hear you sorted it out :)